# Click counter using html data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, server-side, click-counting

Having a collection of articles in divs
each divs have a data attribute "data-click" the purpose is to store the number of click on each article

My question is :
Is it possible to code a click counter using only the data-attribute but in server side, i mean each time a user click on article, the "data-click" attribute change in the server side (html code of the website).

The purpose is to create a dynamic table of most read articles ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. There are no such thing as a server side data attribute.